# Jasper report yearly transactional data gouping

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports

I have a collection with daily transactions data for a year in MongoDB.
I have to get the daily transaction details summary with totals of some fields.
How to achieve this in jasper report?

Transaction collection is having following fields:

id              :   1

date/time       :   "2015-01-01T00:00:00 000Z"

Gross Sales     :   500

SalesTax        :   100

Cash Sales      :   300

i want the output in following 3 format

![1 Week Data][1]

[image: Yearly data on monthly basis]

[image: Yearly data on weekly basis]

Comment: you are missing image

Comment: You can use crosstab. Samples are [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/crosstabs/index.html#crosstabs)